# How do I fix this bug in xCode?

Tags: swift, xcode

No matter what program I run in xCode (as long as there is an `@IBOutlet` in the View Controller), I get the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

In this case, my code is a simple image slideshow:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var imagesNames = ["image-3.jpeg","image-4.jpeg","image-5.jpeg","image-6.jpeg","image-7.jpeg"]

    var images = [UIImage]()

    for i in 0..<imagesNames.count{
        images.append(UIImage(named: imagesNames[i])!)
    }

    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 0.05
    imageView.startAnimating()
}
```

I'm not sure if I used `viewDidAppear()` correctly but it doesn't work if the code is in a `viewDidLoad()` as well. And yes, my `@IBOutlet` is connected in the storyboard with the little gray dot next to it filled in.

I have tried redownloading xCode. Should I try again?

Thanks

e

Comment: You can change that for loop to a simple map call: `let images = imageNames.map{ UIImage(named: $0)! }`

Comment: Have your five images been added to the project?

Comment: @AMomchilov While that thoroughly simplifies the code (and I not only credit you with that, I appreciate you for that) it fails to address the problem which lies in the UIImage itself (I believe

Comment: @vacawama Yes they have. Again, I sincerely doubt an answer to my problem lies in this one specific project. I believe there is something wrong with xCode on my computer which I hope to discover. If I'm incorrect, I will gladly accept that and move on with my project but this is not the only problem in which this exact error has occured.

Comment: When does it crash ? Have you tried debugging ?

Comment: @Emet No, I'm afraid it doesn't. That's why I posted that tidbit as a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @AlexBIt crashes at the `images.append(UIImage(named: imagesNames[i])!)` line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an unwanted outlet referenced in the storyboard...

It happens when a View has a referenced outlet that is missing in the uiviewcontroller code.

Make sure that all referenced outlets are linked to your UIViewController :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the problem does not lie in faulty outlets.

Comment: Are you sure ? I had the same problem quite often and this was the error

Comment: Under the Referencing Outlets section for the image, the one outlet is from imageView to Slideshow (the name of the view).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is if the force unwrapping of `UIImage` is finding nil for one of your images. To double check that it's not funny business on your end you should safely unwrap the image (which is good practice anyway). Try this and see if you're still getting the error:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var imagesNames = ["image-3.jpeg","image-4.jpeg","image-5.jpeg","image-6.jpeg","image-7.jpeg"]

    var images = [UIImage]()

    for i in  0..<imagesNames.count {
        guard let image = UIImage(named: imagesNames[i]) else {
            print("\(imagesNames[i]) not found!"); continue 
        }
        images.append(image)
    }

    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 0.05
    imageView.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: So this returns that all of the images are not found (`image-3.jpeg not found!`)...how could that be?

Comment: Oh and the error comes at the `imageView.animationImages = images` line

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of where your images are stored within your app's directory?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to attach a screenshot but their path is as follows: `/Users/Emet/Desktop/breakthrough_final/breakthrough_final/images-3.jpeg` where `breakthrough_final` is the name of the project.

Comment: They are in the same folder as my ViewController and AppDelagate (not in Assets)

Comment: Unless you named the images wrong (`jpeg` instead of `jpg`) then I can't help you unless you edit your original question and upload a screenshot of your directory structure with images included.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the unconnected outlet. probably you have remove variables in viewcontroller file but forgot to remove the connected outlet

[image: step to follow]